# Tensorflow - Model Only Predicting 2 Classes Out of 6

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am building a CNN to classify 6 classes with 50x50 pixel grayscale images (1400 per class).. After training the model and evaluating the loss and accuracy everything seems to working fine with a training accuracy of around 98% and loss down to 3.0, but when evaluating the model on test data for each class the model is way off. The classes i have are images of facial expressions: 
1) anger
2) fear
3) happy
4) neutral
5) sad
6) suprise

Here is the Jupyter Notebook: https://www.floydhub.com/arse123/projects/cnn-1/20/code/train_edge.ipynb

For example, when i feed 350 test images for each classes only the **anger** and **suprise** classes are ever predicted.

```
    TEST IMAGES                   RESULTS
    Angry -    it classified 76 angry, and 273 surprise

    Fear -     it classified 8 angry and 342 surprise

    Happy -    12 angry and 338 surprise

    Neutral -   350 surprise

    Sad -       22 angry and 328 surprise

    Surprise - a full 350/350 classified for this one..
```

Its clear that there is some bias towards angry and surprise as not one of the other images were classified once.

When i ran `acc.eval({x: test_images, y: test_labels, is_training : False})` (which is 2100 images for each class and the corresponding) after training i got an accuracy of 82%, so i dont know how this is happening. Is it possible that the model some how could have been training on these two classes the whole time?

@NOTE: images and labels are one hot encoded, also randomly shuffled, batch normalization implemented

---

**UPDATE**

---

I retrained the model and it is having the same affect, but with different classes. This time it favours sad and suprise, rather than angry and suprise. 
Here are the results:

```
Angry - Sad 259 and surprise 75
Fear - Sad 118 and surprise 218 (some classifications missing here for some reason)
Happy - Sad 167 times and suprise 160 times (same again, missing some classifications)
Neutral - sad 94 and surprise 249
Sad - sad 211 and surprise 122
Surprise - Sad 284 and surprise 52
```

Comment: It looks like cell [5] shoes your labels have the same one-hot encoding... is that true?

Comment: Yes they are one hot encoded, but that was just chance they all seemed to be nearly the same, i have checked  ***labels[0:100]*** and the labels are shuffled correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few things with the code but the most important thing is that for some reason it's not behaving when `is_training = False`. If you set `is_training = True` ***even when not training*** then it gives acceptable results. So the training is okay, but the evaluation doesn't run okay.

Now why would that be is a question I cannot answer right now but is probably worthy of investigation.

Attaching fixed code in Jupyter Notebook. I've changed many small things, like you took the Softmax of the already Softmaxed value, fixed that, changed random shuffling to use numpy, changed loading of test images to do the resizing immediately upon loading, etc. Also have a lot of debug printing going on, sorry about that. :)

Looks reasonable with 88% validation accuracy (training accuracy 96.59%). (Changed to 10 epochs, too.)

[train_edge_v2.ipynb](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sDUbVPTG-he4_rMNwlkOm1A1QWXjyunn)